# Is publishing of magic statics thread safe?

Tags: c++11, static, thread-safety

Imagine I have this:

```
const string& get_name()
{
static auto* ptr_name=new string("Ron");
return *ptr_name;
}
```

If multiple threads are calling get_name is that UB or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is thread safe in C++11 and forward.

VS-2013 has not yet implemented this part of C++11.  VS-14 does:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/11/c-11-14-feature-tables-for-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx

Comment: I have known about magic statics, I just did not know if publishing that static by returning it from a function is race free.

Comment: race free was a wrong terminology... I was thinking about sequential consistency... Aka can users of a function see garbage or null as returned value, or if they see the real address of string can they see garbage where address points to(instead of "Ron")

Comment: Also see [Runtime crash with static std::mutex](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808030/runtime-crash-with-static-std-mutex) on Microsoft Connect, [Visual C++ 2015 runtime broken on Windows Server 2003 (C++11 magic statics)](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1789709/visual-c-2015-runtime-broken-on-windows-server-2003-c-11-magic-statics) on Microsoft Connect, and any number of posts about crashes on Stack Overflow. Microsoft screwed this up bigtime.

Answer (score 2):

Since C++11, initialization of function scope static variables is *thread safe* : the first tread calling `get_name()` will initialize `ptr_name`, blocking other threads until the initialization is completed. All subsequent calls will use the initialized value.

With prior C++ implementations, there is no such guarantee and all bets are off