# Is asignment of a local static reference thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've read other questions on StackOverflow about the subject but I'm not positive they answer this question which combines a few different details. Is the following code that initializes a local static const reference with a lambda thread-safe?

```
std::vector<int> a, b, c;

void foo()
{
    static auto const& v = [](){ /* logic to return a or b or c */ }();
}
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, I did. Edited to reflect intent.

Comment: This is thread-safe for [C++11 and onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181645/is-publishing-of-magic-statics-thread-safe).

Comment: It's safe provided your initialization logic doesn't call `foo` again.